# SwiftUI: How to override a TextField's value from within itself when tabbing out of field on macOS

Tags: macos, swiftui, textfield

I'm trying to limit the text entry of a TextField based on existing values to eliminate duplicate entries. I'm changing the entered value if I detect a duplicate.

[image]

My code works. If I detect a wrong value and try to replace it then the value is overwritten correctly. Even though the debugger shows the correct value, the change does not get reflected back into the TextField (or into the Text).

Here is my code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View
{

    @State var text: String = ""
    @State var text2: String = ""
    @State var text3: String = ""
    @State var displayText: String = ""

    var body: some View
    {
        VStack
        {
            Text ("If I enter 12345 into this textbox then it will not change to 00000, displayText does get changed!")
            TextField("Select an item", text: $text)
            {
               if text == "12345"
                {
                    text = "00000"
                    displayText = "00000"
                }
                else
                {
                    displayText = text
                }
            }
            .padding(.bottom, 20)
            
            Text ("This works but only if I press return. Tabbing and clicking out does not work so this is no good")
            TextField("Select an item", text: $text2)
                .onSubmit
            {
                if text2 == "12345"
                {
                    self.text2 = "00000"
                }
            }
            .padding(.bottom, 20)

            Text ("This works on key press but you can never type 12345. I need to validate it once the full string is entered.")
            TextField("Select an item", text: $text3)
                .onChange (of: text3)
            { value in
                if value == "12"
                {
                    self.text3 = "XX"
                }
                else if value == "12345"
                {
                    self.text3 = "00000"
                }
            }
            .padding(.bottom, 20)

            Text(text)
            Text(displayText)
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

If you enter "12345" into the TextField and tab out the variable will be updated to "00000" and displayText too but the TextField stubbornly still shows "12345".

I do not want to use .onChange because that gets fired off with each key press and would generate false positives (annoyingly .onChange does correctly update the text value).

i.e. if my database had already the following values:

1, 12, 123 then trying to type 12345 with .onChange would find a false duplicate after typing just 1.

I don't want to use .onSubmit as this only gets fired on pressing return. I need it to run on tabbing out or clicking to another field.

How can I get the desired functionality?

Answer (score 1):

try using `.onSubmit{...}`, like this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var text: String = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        TextField("Select an item", text: $text)
            .onSubmit {
                if text == "12345" {
                    text = "00000"
                }
            }
            .padding()
        Text(text)
    }
}
```

You can also use this approach, to update the `text` in the `TextField`, as you type:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var text: String = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        TextField("Select an item", text: Binding<String>(
            get: { text } ,
            set: { txt in
                if txt == "12345" {
                    text = "00000"
                } else {
                    text = txt
                }
            })
        )
        .padding()
        Text(text)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply but .onSubmit is only fired when pressing return from the field. Nothing appears to happen if you tab or click away. How do I get the code to be invoked when leaving the TextField? Your second example does not allow it to be expanded to also test for txt == "12" etc.

Comment: you describe another question in your comment, `How do I get the code to be invoked when leaving the TextField?`. I was addressing your original question `How to override a TextField's value from within itself macOS`.  Does the `TextField` not update as required with my answer? What exactly is your question here?

Comment: I have reworded my question to more accurately reflect my problem.